# tmux not starting a python script from cron

Tags: bash, cron, python, raspberry-pi, tmux

I am having issues with cron *(Debian bullseye - Raspberry Pi 4)* not starting a tmux session from a bash script I gave it to run on @reboot.

Here is the problematic fragment of my bash script:

```
pythonPATH="/usr/bin/python"
serverPATH="/opt/Hyxer_Chat/HyxerChat_Server.py"
consolePATH="/opt/Hyxer_Chat/Chat_Console"
tmuxPATH="/usr/bin/tmux"

"$tmuxPATH" -S "$consolePATH" new -d "$pythonPATH" "$serverPATH"

chown :kubaroot "$consolePATH"
chmod 664 "$consolePATH"
```

**This script fully works when I run it manually**, like so: `bash /opt/myscript.sh`
I have made sure all paths to all files and programs are absolute, as described in this post: [Link to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574458/how-to-run-a-bash-script-via-cron)

The issue I am having is that cron seems to just skip this part of my script. I have added little `echo "Hello!" > /opt/hello.txt` lines to of code to make sure cron does indeed run my bash script in full, and it does. Upon restarting the Pi I was always greated with a hello.txt file, however never any tmux session was created and I have never seen my python script running in htop.

**In case it is important**, my python script is supposed to be running continiously and it monitors the network, as it's a chat service server. If a connection to the Pi's local adress in my home network cannot be established, it quits.

Here is my crontab configuration:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /opt/Hyxer_Chat/run.sh
```

What could be causing the problem? I did also try commenting the tmux line and running just a script like this:

```
pythonPATH="/usr/bin/python"
serverPATH="/opt/Hyxer_Chat/HyxerChat_Server.py"
    
"$pythonPATH" "$serverPATH"
```

However again, I did not see the python script running in htop.

Thank You for the help.

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue. As mentioned in the "In case it's important" section, my script needs an internet connection to function. Seems like cron was starting the script before a network connection got established. Thus causing my script to exit on startup. I do not know a proper solution to the problem, but adding a sleep 60 command to the cron task seems to have temporarily resolved the issue. Now cron simply waits 60s after a reboot before starting my script. Enough time for the network connection to be established.

Comment: Any reason you are not doing this as a `systemd` service?  You can make it start on boot after network is available and keep it running until you no longer want it to do so.